# Debugging AJAX requests

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, debugging

I am currently trying to figure out how I can find out what errors are in my php script.

I have made a small script which an error on purpose. Using the chrome console I get...

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

However, normally PHP errors would point you to the line in which the error occurs.

Here is my AJAX Request.

```
var myData = "Hello";

        $.ajax({ 
            type: "GET",
            url: 'test.php',
            datatype: 'json',
            data: { data: myData},
            success: function(output) {
                var result = $.parseJSON(output);
                for(var i=0; i<result.length; i++){
                    console.log(result[i]);
                }
            }
        });
```

And my PHP script with the syntax error

```
$data = ($_GET['data']);
echoo boom;
echo json_encode(array($data, "test"));
```

As you can see, line 2 is the error but the error in my console gives me no information as such.

Thanks

Comment: That error means that the response is not formatted correctly to the expected return type. In this case it means your JSON is not correctly fotmatted. If you check DevTools (F12) you can see the exact response in the network tab of the console.

Comment: Thank you, I never looked into the console in this much detail, the PHP error is in the network tab

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$.ajax({ 
    type: "GET",
    url: 'test.php',
    datatype: 'json',
    data: {},
    success: function(output) {
        result = output;
        for(var i=0; i < result.length; i++){
            console.log(result[i]);
        }
    }
});
```

By defining the dataType as json the output is already parsed. Parsing the already parsed 'output' again led to the error. So it was a client side / javascript error.

ALso note that - in case an error occurs - the actual error message is parsed too. So you get an array containing the "fragmented" error message from the server ;)

Comment: You can also check what response you got from the server before JQuery processes it. Check your console (Network->select the last entry->Response). If you see your error here you have another mistake on your client side

Answer (score 1):

When the error is server side you typically only get an error message (maybe 500 or Server Error) on the client side which is very non-specific. You must debug on the web server. Once I see such an error I check out the web server's error log file (which will show both compile and run time errors).

Comment: I am using Localhost xampp. Do you know how I can do that using this?

Comment: I'm not familiar with that environment. But somewhere you have log files. Otherwise, if you have the command line version of PHP enabled, you can do php -l test.php (which will show you compile errors only). You will need to examine the log files for run time errors.

Answer (score 0):

Please write :

```
$data = $_GET['data'];
echo boom;
echo json_encode(array($data, "test"));
```

Instead of :

```
$data = ($_GET['data']);
echoo boom;
echo json_encode(array($data, "test"));
```

And write :

```
$.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: "test.php",
                timeout: 6000,
                success: function(data) {


                    json = $.parseJSON(data);

                    for (var i = 0; i <= json.length-120; i++) {


                        console.log(json[i]);


                    }



                }
});
```

Comment: What's the difference?

Comment: I don't think you understand my question.

Comment: The OP isn't asking what the error is.  The error was *intentional* to test debugging efforts.  The OP is asking how to debug something like this in order to determine a less obvious error.

Comment: I know this, I was doing a test

Answer (score 0):

Use the debugging tools in your browser.  Specifically look for a tab or set of functionality for monitoring network requests.  This will show you the actual request and response to and from the server in your AJAX.

What's happening here is your PHP code is generating an error, which results in returning some kind of HTML to the browser (possibly showing the error message).  However, look at what you're doing with the response:

```
var result = $.parseJSON(output);
```

If `output` is HTML and not JSON, then this code will fail with an error.  Since JSON syntax doesn't use `<` but HTML does, I would expect you to get the error:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```